# pr2 cannot install pr2_robot

Tags: ros, source, robot, pr2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While debugging audio drivers on the pr2 robot the package `pr2_robot` was unintentionally uninstalled. I cannot seem to install `ros-indigo-pr2-robot` again. `pr2_robot` is also a dependency for `pr2-core` which needs to be reinstalled.

I followed the instructions here.
http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/pr2/UpdatingSourcesList.html
and here
http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/pr2/InstallingPR2Trusty.html

The problem being the prior Clearpath server is no longer available as far as I can tell

http://clearpathrobotics.com/pr2-packages/ubuntu
ec2-52-37-150-147.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/  http://ec2-52-37-150-147.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

I emailed Clearpath for a replacement location and they replied with this url

```
http://52.35.195.135/   
http://ec2-52-35-195-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

I tired to get the key via this command

```
sudo wget http://ec2-52-35-195-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/pr2packages.gpg | sudo apt-key add
```

and then updated my source list to look like this

```
deb http://ec2-52-35-195-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ubuntu trusty pr2  
deb http://ec2-52-35-195-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

This includes many of the pr2 debs but does not include the install for ros-indigo-pr2-robot.
I still get this result

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install  ros-indigo-pr2-robot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ros-indigo-pr2-robot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ros-indigo-pr2-robot' has no installation candidate
```

Is there anther location I am missing that needs to be added to my source lists or a way to manually install `ros-indigo-pr2-robot` so that `pr2-core` can be installed?

Please let me know any additional information that may help.
Thanks for any assistance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285162/pr2-cannot-install-pr2_robot/) by [CodyLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/6160/codyll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although I would not call it the cleanest solution I did manage to get the pr2 working again.
As I could not find a proper install method for `ros-indigo-pr2_robot` and the install did not actually contain much I used the program equivs to trick apt into thinking it was installed to fulfill the dependency of other packages I needed to install. I used this method
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85928/how-to-make-apt-recognize-an-installed-tar-package/86052#86052

These are the exact commands

$ sudo apt-get install equivs  
$ mkdir equivs_test
$ cd equivs_test/  
$ equivs-control ros-indigo-pr2-robot.control
$ nano ros-indigo-pr2-robot.control  
    the primary line changed was package: ros-indigo-pr2-robot  
$ equivs-build ros-indigo-pr2-robot.control
$ sudo dpkg -i ros-indigo-pr2-robot_1.0_all.deb  
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-robot
states newest version is already installed as I hoped

I then installed the main pr2 packages in a somewhat random order

$ sudo apt-get install pr2-installer  
$ sudo apt-get install pr2-chrony pr2-ckill pr2-core pr2-core-indigo pr2-environment pr2-ft pr2-iptables.d pr2-net* pr2-nuc-ssh pr2-sys* pr2-users pr2-webui

`pr2-webui` would not install. I saved the original output of these commands if anyone is interested.

I can now run the command `robot start` and the robot is beeping on boot unlike before but c2 is not booting correctly by default. I can get c2 to boot correctly by starting the robot and letting c2 boot into the clearpath OS then running the service `dnsmasq` manually on c1.

$ sudo service dnsmasq stop  
$ sudo dnsmasq -d   # -d is optional to see debug info

When `dnsmasq` is running on c1 simply reboot the clearpath OS on c2 using a monitor and keyboard and it will netboot correctly from c1. `robot start` is now successful on c1.

I set the service `dnsmasq` to run on startup on c1. I do not know if this was necessary or even a good thing to do but it did not solve the problem. I am including it here simple for debugging and records.

$ sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq defaults  
$ sudo update-rc.d dnsmasq enable
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match dnsmasq Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match dnsmasq Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
Enabling system startup links for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
/etc/rc0.d/K01dnsmasq
/etc/rc1.d/K01dnsmasq
/etc/rc2.d/S99dnsmasq
/etc/rc3.d/S99dnsmasq
/etc/rc4.d/S99dnsmasq
/etc/rc5.d/S99dnsmasq
/etc/rc6.d/K01dnsmasq
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/dnsmasq ...
/etc/rc0.d/K01dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc1.d/K01dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc6.d/K01dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc2.d/S99dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc3.d/S99dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc4.d/S99dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq
/etc/rc5.d/S99dnsmasq -> ../init.d/dnsmasq

I then found this to help debug `dnsmasq` on the pr2
https://github.com/hcrlab/wiki/commit/e86e7bc2401d3f80c6c51db3ad2371b10eb253b2
After making these changes to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` the pr2 boots and calibrates correctly. Multiple demos have also been run successfully without any additional problems.

If anyone finds a cleaner method or suggestion for this problem please let me know.

---

Originally posted by [CodyLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/6160/codyll/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1